# Errors installing/loading package ‘adespatial’

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to run the `dbmem` function on a large dataset using the **adespatial** package, but cannot get it to install. When I run `install.package("adespatial)`, I get this message:

> package ‘adespatial’ is available as a source package but not as a binary.

Why can't I install this package as a binary and how do I go about getting this package installed on my Mac (OS sierra version 10.12.6). I am running R studio with R version 3.1.2

---

### Update

I also tried running

```
install.packages("adespatial",type = "source")
```

however when I try to load the library it still says the library is not found.  There were also many errors in the install. I updated my version of R to 3.4.4 and now it will install with a few errors, but the library still will not come up.

When I attempt to load the library (`library(adespatial)`), I receive this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adespatial’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘curl’

Comment: Try installing from source `install.package("adespatial", type="source")` It might have something to do with the fact your are running a fairly old version of R.

Comment: I tried running install.packages("adespatial",type = "source"), however when I try to load the library it still says the library is not found. There were also many errors in the install. I updated my version of R to 3.4.4 and now it will install with a few errors, but the library still will not come up. this is the error I receive:    > library(adespatial)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adespatial’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘curl’

Comment: @AlexZalmat looks like you need to install **curl**, but I suspect you might have other libraries missing as well.  Please include the error messages you are getting when installing **adespatial** (add as edits to your question, not as a comment).  You really have to have zero errors during install, else it is highly likely to not work again.

Answer (score 1):

Bit hard to replicate your problem, but try to install `curl`; either the R package:

```
install.packages("curl")
```

or directly on your OS (can't help there, sorry, never had an OS).

Anyway, if package installation fails in R, it throws an (or more) error message(s). In your case, they will point to missing packages. Rerun `install.packages("adespatial")` and see there.